# how to detect a RSA private key has passphrase in node

Tags: node.js

my node version: v10.15.3

I tried to use an api like `crypto.privateDecrypt(privateKey, Buffer.from(encryptData, 'utf8'))`
I got an error: `Error: error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt`

I understand we can pass the passphrase like `{key:privateKey, passphrase: 'im_passphrase'}`, but I would like to detect if this private key has a passphrase.

any idea?

Comment: You might find the higher level functionality in Forge more helpful:  https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is not achievable with native `crypto` module. But as of this [question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/129724/how-to-check-if-an-ssh-private-key-has-passphrase-or-not) in security exchange. You can check that reading the file and this can be achieved by file system (fs) module.

```
const fs = require('fs');

const get_line =  (filename, line_no, callback) => {
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(filename, {
      flags: 'r',
      encoding: 'utf-8',
      fd: null,
      mode: 0666,
      bufferSize: 64 * 1024
    });

    let fileData = '';

    stream.on('data', (data) => {
      fileData += data;

      // The next lines should be improved
      let lines = fileData.split("\n");

      if(lines.length >= +line_no){
        stream.destroy();
        callback(null, lines[+line_no]);
      }
    });

    stream.on('error', () => {
      callback('Error', null);
    });

    stream.on('end', () => {
      callback('File end reached without finding line', null);
    });
}

const hasPassphrase = (keyFile, callback) => {
    get_line(keyFile, 1, (err, line) => {
        if (line.indexOf("Proc-Type:") === -1) {
            callback(false);
        } else {
            callback(true);
        }
    })
}

hasPassphrase('./ssh-Key', hasPasspharse => {
    // your logic here
});
```

You get the idea right, extract the second line of the file and check if there is `Proc-Type:` header. Edit this code as it suits you.

Comment: hmmm, it is probably fair enough to detect it. by the way, it should be `get_line(keyFile, 1, (err, line) => ...` 
thanks

Comment: Changed that :)